# Is it possible to add a Hoover box to the graph drawn, in order to display the values of the failure points and the values of the lines drawn?

Tags: r, shiny

I would like to display the coordinates of the points plotted on the Weibull sheet, these points are plotted by the plot.wblr function which belongs to the WeibullR package, is it possible to display them? if yes you can help me to plot them

you can find my code below

```
library(WeibullR)
library(DT)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(fitdistrplus)

Weibull_Input <- data.frame(
  State_End_Time=c(10,20,30,40,50),
  State=c("Failed","Failed","Failed","Failed","Suspended"),
  Failure_Mode="")
Weibull_Input<-Weibull_Input[!is.na(Weibull_Input$State),]
Weibull_Input<-Weibull_Input[!is.na(Weibull_Input$State_End_Time),]
Weibull_Input<- Weibull_Input[Weibull_Input$State_End_Time>0,]
print(Weibull_Input)

if(mean(Weibull_Input[,"State_End_Time"])==0 |length(Weibull_Input[,"State_End_Time"])<2|length(Weibull_Input[,"State_End_Time"]>0)==1 ){ Weibull_Input} else {
  Weibull_Input$Number_in_State<-1
  names(Weibull_Input)<-c("State_End_Time", "State", "Failure_Mode","Number_in_State")
  Weibull_Input[c("left", "right", "qty")]<-0
  Weibull_Input$qty<-Weibull_Input$Number_in_State

  Weibull_Input$Failure_Mode<-NULL
  #### WE NOW APPLY A MUTATE FUNCTION
  Weibull_Input<-Weibull_Input%>%mutate(left=State_End_Time)%>%
    mutate(right=if_else(State=="Suspended", NA, left))%>%
    mutate(state=if_else(State=="Failed", 1,0))
}
  Failure_Suspended_Bind<-Weibull_Input
  Failure_Suspended_Bind<-Failure_Suspended_Bind[Failure_Suspended_Bind$left>0 & Failure_Suspended_Bind$State_End_Time>0,]
  Failure_Suspended_Bind<-Failure_Suspended_Bind[Failure_Suspended_Bind$qty>0,]
  if(is.null(Failure_Suspended_Bind))
    return(NULL)
  req(Failure_Suspended_Bind)
  left<-Failure_Suspended_Bind$left
  right<-Failure_Suspended_Bind$right
  qty<-Failure_Suspended_Bind$qty
  state<-Failure_Suspended_Bind$state
  d = data.frame(time=left,event =state)
  da1<-wblr(d,dist="weibull2p",method.fit="mle",method.conf="fm")
  ppp <- getPPP(d,ppos="beta")
  da1[["data"]][["dpoints"]][["ppp"]] <- ppp$ppp
  da1 <- wblr.fit(da1 ,dist= "weibull2p",method.fit="mle")
  Confidence<-0.9
  da1<-wblr.conf(da1,method.conf="fm",ci=as.numeric(Confidence),col="Red")
  da1
  plot.wblr( da1, main = NA ,col.main = "red", col.lable = "blue",col.grid ="green4")
```